# Opening .1X1 (grid) files?

Tags: data, files

I am an economics student working on a paper for which I need to find and analyze regional data for SO2 emissions.
I came across some .1x1 data files but I don't have any idea how to open/display these files.

Comment: Where did you get them from? did you ask the suppliers how to use them

Comment: Can you tell us any more about the files or link one here?  Even telling us the file extension would be a start.  Without any further info I'd suggest grabbing a copy of QGIS (free) and giving it a go.